# Laravel with html2canvas not saving the image

Tags: javascript, laravel, html2canvas

I want to take a screenshot of a div using Html2canvas. It throws no error in console but only gives an empty canvas.

```js
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#myId"), {
    async: true,
    logging: false,
    backgroundColor: null,
    allowTaint: true,
    foreignObjectRendering: true,
    removeContainer: true
}).then(canvas => {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    window.open(dataURL);
});
```

I tried `logging: true` `allowTaint: true` `useCORS: true` but it didn't work

Comment: Can you share what the error in the console is? Also response you receive from the Network tab.

Comment: It throws no error in console. I tried  `$ ('body'). get (0)` is ok but using `$("#myId")`  is not possible @thefallen

Answer (score 0):

remove foreignObjectRendering and try again